# Flutter Exception: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

My Flutter application is throwing an exception (ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views) when navigating away from a page that has a `ScrollController` to control a `NestedScrollView` and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have recreated the exception with a simple example below. I can navigate from `FirstPage` to `SecondPage` (and optionally back) just fine, but when I navigate from `SecondPage` to `ThirdPage` the exception is thrown. The `SecondPage` is the page that contains my custom `CollapsingAppBarPage` widget which I assume has the problem. `CollapsingAppBarPage` is simplified in this example, but in my real app it changes colors/sizes of components based on the scroll position. In this example, the exception happens when `_scrollController.offset` is called as the navigation begins to the `ThirdPage`. Also, I know FirstPage and ThirdPage could be Stateless instead of StatefulWidgets but I wanted to make it as much like my app as possible. Here is my fully working example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Navigate Next"),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage())
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: CollapsingAppBarPage(
        titleText: "Second Page",
        bodyCreator: (context) {
          return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Navigate Next"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdPage())
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThirdPageState createState() => _ThirdPageState();
}

class _ThirdPageState extends State<ThirdPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Third Page")
        ),
        body: Container()
    );
  }
}

typedef CollapsingAppBarBodyCreator = Widget Function(BuildContext context);

class CollapsingAppBarPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final String titleText;
  final CollapsingAppBarBodyCreator bodyCreator;

  CollapsingAppBarPage({
    Key key,
    this.titleText,
    @required this.bodyCreator,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CollapsingAppBarPageState createState() => _CollapsingAppBarPageState();
}

class _CollapsingAppBarPageState extends State<CollapsingAppBarPage> {

  static const _kExpandedHeight = 200.0;

  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // force a refresh so the app bar can be updated
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: _createSliverAppBar,
      body: widget.bodyCreator(context),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _createSliverAppBar(BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    // change the icon color as the page scrolls
    var collapsePercent = _getAppBarCollapsePercent();
    int rgb = ((1.0 - collapsePercent) * 255).round();
    var color = Color.fromARGB(255, rgb, rgb, rgb);

    return <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: _kExpandedHeight,
        pinned: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: color),
        title: Text(widget.titleText),
      )
    ];
  }

  double _getAppBarCollapsePercent() {
    if (!_scrollController.hasClients)
      return 0.0;

    return (_scrollController.offset / (_kExpandedHeight - kToolbarHeight)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
  }
}
```

Here is a truncated trace of the exception:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty):
flutter: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 111 pos 12:
flutter: '_positions.length == 1'
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #2      ScrollController.position (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:111:12)
flutter: #3      ScrollController.offset (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:118:24)
flutter: #4      _CollapsingAppBarPageState._getAppBarCollapsePercent (package:flutter_scroll_test/main.dart:160:31)
flutter: #5      _CollapsingAppBarPageState._createSliverAppBar (package:flutter_scroll_test/main.dart:142:27)
flutter: #6      NestedScrollView._buildSlivers (package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart:271:20)
flutter: #7      _NestedScrollViewState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart:347:29)
flutter: #8      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:5736:41)
flutter: #9      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3774:28)
flutter: #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:15)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't use `_scrollController.offset` directly as pushing routes apparently attach a scroll position to be retrieved when you approach scrolling when you pop again

so we need to transfer it into a piece of state

this is the complete revised code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Navigate Next"),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage())
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: CollapsingAppBarPage(
        titleText: "Second Page",
        bodyCreator: (context) {
          return ListView(

            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Navigate Next"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdPage())
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThirdPageState createState() => _ThirdPageState();
}

class _ThirdPageState extends State<ThirdPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Third Page")
        ),
        body: Container()
    );
  }
}

typedef CollapsingAppBarBodyCreator = Widget Function(BuildContext context);

class CollapsingAppBarPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final String titleText;
  final CollapsingAppBarBodyCreator bodyCreator;

  CollapsingAppBarPage({
    Key key,
    this.titleText,
    @required this.bodyCreator,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CollapsingAppBarPageState createState() => _CollapsingAppBarPageState();
}

class _CollapsingAppBarPageState extends State<CollapsingAppBarPage> {

  static const _kExpandedHeight = 200.0;

  ScrollController _scrollController;
  //Offset state <-------------------------------------
  double offset = 0.0 ;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //print("init state is called");

    _scrollController = ScrollController() //keepScrollOffset: false removed
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          //<-----------------------------
          offset = _scrollController.offset;
          // force a refresh so the app bar can be updated
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: _createSliverAppBar,
      body: widget.bodyCreator(context),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _createSliverAppBar(BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    // change the icon color as the page scrolls
    print("_createSliverAppBar is called");
    var collapsePercent = _getAppBarCollapsePercent();
    int rgb = ((1.0 - collapsePercent) * 255).round();
    var color = Color.fromARGB(255, rgb, rgb, rgb);

    return <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: _kExpandedHeight,
        pinned: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: color),
        title: Text(widget.titleText),
      )
    ];
  }

  double _getAppBarCollapsePercent() {
    if (!_scrollController.hasClients ){
      print("positions is ${_scrollController.positions.length}");
      return 0.0;

    }


    //print("offset is${_scrollController.offset} and positions is ${_scrollController.positions.length}");
    return (offset / (_kExpandedHeight - kToolbarHeight)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: also watch out for nested scroll controllers. a scroll controller can only have on scroll view in the nest.

Answer (score 51):

If on your case, you have many ListViews on a same views, you will get this error too. And to solve it you just need to add the following property into each listView builder:

```dart
controller: ScrollController(),
```

After you will have :

```dart
ListView.builder(
        controller: ScrollController(),//just add this line
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index]),
          );
```

Source is this link: [Click here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85456)

Comment: Be careful about indiscriminately adding new controllers per listview; things like a ScrollBar may need to share the same controller to interact properly.

Comment: This action creates a new controller for each view and therefore avoids the conflict where several views are fighting over the same controller.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is the `_scrollController.position` or `_scrollController.offset` wherever you are calling the `_scrollController.position` replace it with `_scrollController.positions.last` instead, and wherever you are calling `_scrollController.offset` replace it with `_scrollController.positions.last.pixels` you won't get any error.

Actually the issue is occurring because it is adding new element in the `positions` list of the `_scrollController` and I checked in the `scroll_controller.dart` the `_scrollController.position` returns the `scrollcontroller.positions.single` and `_scrollController.offset` returns `_scrollController.position.pixels` that's why we face this issue.

But if you will use `_scrollController.positions.last` it will return the last saved position element so your app will run smoothly and won't throw any error.

Answer (score 11):

The solution is to mark appropriate *ScrollViews* i.e (*ListView, SingleChildScrollView, CustomScrollView,* etc.)
with attribute `primary: false`, so that you are left with no more than one primary ScrollView

Answer (score 2):

you need to add another condition in `_getAppBarCollapsePercent()` to be

```
 double _getAppBarCollapsePercent() {
    if (!_scrollController.hasClients || _scrollController.positions.length > 1)
      return 0.0;

    return (_scrollController.offset / (_kExpandedHeight - kToolbarHeight)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
  }
```

controller can not give offset if it controls more than one scrollable.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that before but `positions` is a protected member of ScrollController and the compiler gives a warning if you try to access it. While this stops the exceptions, it still does not properly maintain the scroll offset (calculated RGB colors) properly when switching from ThirdPage back to SecondPage. Is there something wrong with my code which is causing multiple scroll positions/clients to be registered?

Answer (score 0):

For one who uses `SingleScrollView`

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

Expanded(
            child: Scrollbar(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    thumbVisibility: true,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      child: _mainView(context),
                    )
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused this, but I solved it temporary by clearing my navigation stacks history, by naviating with this

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const HomeScreen()),
              (route) => false)
```